# go 1.16 embed - strip directory name

Tags: go

i was previously using [statik](https://github.com/rakyll/statik) to embed files into a Go application.

with Go 1.16 i can remove that deps

for example:

```
//go:embed static
var static embed.FS

fs := http.FileServer(http.FS(static))
http.Handle("/", fs)
```

this will serve the `./static/` directory from `http://.../static/`

Is there a way I can serve that directory from `/` root path, without `/static`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [fs.Sub](https://golang.org/pkg/io/fs/#Sub):

> Sub returns an FS corresponding to the subtree rooted at fsys's dir.

```
package main

import (
        "embed"
        "io/fs"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

//go:embed static
var static embed.FS

func main() {
        subFS, _ := fs.Sub(static, "static")

        http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(subFS)))

        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil))
}
```

fs.Sub is also useful in combination with [http.StripPrefix](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) to "rename" a directory. For instance, to "rename" the directory static to public, such that a request for /public/index.html serves static/index.html:

```
//go:embed static
var static embed.FS

subFS, _ := fs.Sub(static, "static")
http.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/public", http.FileServer(http.FS(subFS))))
```

---

Alternatively, create a .go file in the static directory and move the embed directive there (`//go:embed *`). That matches a little more closely what the statik tool does (it creates a whole new package), but is usually unnecessary thanks to fs.Sub.

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "my.module/static"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.FS(static.FS)))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil))
}

// static/static.go
package static

import "embed"

//go:embed *
var FS embed.FS
```

Comment: Will the `static/static.go` embed the Go source file itself?

Comment: @ceving, yes, it does in this case because `*` matches static.go.